# Windows batch online or on mac

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have like to code windows batch and I have a file I wish to test on an apple computer ( just run it; it doesn't have to do anything) is there a way to run it online or on the mac without a virtual machine

Comment: Huh? How can a Windows batch file run on a Mac under OSX?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - Wine, maybe?

Comment: @SomethingDark I didn't realise `wine` included a command interpreter, I though it was a library of the Windows API.

Comment: I honestly don't know; I don't use OSX. If you can't do this in Wine, you have to use a Virtual Machine, since there is no online version of CMD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install Wine on your system, and run it from there.

If you don't want to use Wine, then you'd have to borrow someone's computer, that runs Windows.